# Ajax Autosuggestion Search with PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for an Ajax autosuggested Search with PHP that can handle with mistypes of Words.

If you mistype a Word like EURPE it should still show EUROPE. I have found already a Script but that one will not show mistypes. Would be happy about any advice.

Ajax Search Demo: http://www.freezecoders.com/demos/Google-like-auto-suggest-search-using-ajax-php/

Comment: Take the example you found and add logic to handle common mis-types.

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is I can't code in PHP or Javascript. Thats why I am looking for ready to use scripts that I can modify.

Comment: What you're asking for can be a complex task if it's done well.  Google has the best minds on the planet designing systems to efficiently and effectively capture and understand user intent. It's not something you can easily plug-and-play - especially if you don't understand the basics of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try use jquerui auto-complete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for something that can handle with mistypes and show anyway the correct result.